# Match expression that is not between quote

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to be able to extract an expression from a string. But I need this expression not to be between quotes.

For example I need to be able to extract `return`, `if` and `eq` (perl keywords) from this kind of string : `return 3 + 4 if $string eq "time is eq";`

I don't retrieve the `time` even if it's a keyword because it is between quotes.

So far this is what I've tried:

- `m/((("(\\"|[^"])*")|[^"])*)(^|\s|<)+${keywords}(\s|\(|>|$|\n)/g`
- I also tried to check the end of the string and see if I had an even/odd number of quotes.

The problem on the first solution is that it does not match the keyword if there are spaces and then the keyword.
The problem for the second solution is that if there is a second keyword in the string and a string between quotes after the second keyword, the latest won't be matched.

I would like to know how to fix this I've been working on this for a while and it's driving me crazy! :)

Thank you!

PS: Someone asked me for the keyword list here it is:

```
my $keywords = qr/(-A|END|length|setpgrp|-B|endgrent|link|setpriority|-b|endhostent|listen|setprotoent|-C|endnetent|local|setpwent|-c|endprotoent|localtime|setservent|-d|endpwent|log|setsockopt|-e|endservent|lstat|shift|-f|eof|map|shmctl|-g|eval|mkdir|shmget|-k|exec|msgctl|shmread|-l|exists|msgget|shmwrite|-M|exit|msgrcv|shutdown|-O|fcntl|msgsnd|sin|-o|fileno|my|sleep|-p|flock|next|socket|-r|fork|not|socketpair|-R|format|oct|sort|-S|formline|open|splice|-s|getc|opendir|split|-T|getgrent|ord|sprintf|-t|getgrgid|our|sqrt|-u|getgrnam|pack|srand|-w|gethostbyaddr|pipe|stat|-W|gethostbyname|pop|state|-X|gethostent|pos|study|-x|getlogin|print|substr|-z|getnetbyaddr|printf|symlink|abs|getnetbyname|prototype|syscall|accept|getnetent|push|sysopen|alarm|getpeername|quotemeta|sysread|atan2|getpgrp|rand|sysseek|AUTOLOAD|getppid|read|system|BEGIN|getpriority|readdir|syswrite|bind|getprotobyname|readline|tell|binmode|getprotobynumber|readlink|telldir|bless|getprotoent|readpipe|tie|break|getpwent|recv|tied|caller|getpwnam|redo|time|chdir|getpwuid|ref|times|CHECK|getservbyname|rename|truncate|chmod|getservbyport|require|uc|chomp|getservent|reset|ucfirst|chop|getsockname|return|umask|chown|getsockopt|reverse|undef|chr|glob|rewinddir|UNITCHECK|chroot|gmtime|rindex|unlink|close|goto|rmdir|unpack|closedir|grep|say|unshift|connect|hex|scalar|untie|cos|index|seek|use|crypt|INIT|seekdir|utime|dbmclose|int|select|values|dbmopen|ioctl|semctl|vec|defined|join|semget|wait|delete|keys|semop|waitpid|DESTROY|kill|send|wantarray|die|last|setgrent|warn|dump|lc|sethostent|write|each|lcfirst|setnetent|__DATA__|else|lock|qw|__END__|elsif|lt|qx|__FILE__|eq|m|s|__LINE__|exp|ne|sub|__PACKAGE__|for|no|tr|and|foreach|or|unless|cmp|ge|package|until|continue|gt|q|while|CORE|if|qq|xor|do|le|qr|y|ARGV|STDERR|STDOUT|ARGVOUT|STDIN)/;
```

Comment: Please provide a string example along with what you want extracted

Comment: Can you give us an example of that expression?

Comment: and why dont you extract `$string` or `+` or `3` or `4`

Comment: Because $string is a variable, 3 and 4 are numbers, and + is not a word for my consideration. I have a list of those keywords this is why it is in a variable

Comment: then please provide the list dear which you want to blacklist

Answer (score 1):

one idea :

search and replace with blank:

```
".*?"|\$\w+
```

this will remove all the strings which are variables i.e. starting with `$` and all words inside double quotes.

after this you can use your normal regex to find all the words to match :

```
/(-A|END|length|setpgrp|-B|endgrent|link|setpriority|-b|endhostent|listen|setprotoent|-C|endnetent|local|setpwent|-c|endprotoent|localtime|setservent|-d|endpwent|log|setsockopt|-e|endservent|lstat|shift|-f|eof|map|shmctl|-g|eval|mkdir|shmget|-k|exec|msgctl|shmread|-l|exists|msgget|shmwrite|-M|exit|msgrcv|shutdown|-O|fcntl|msgsnd|sin|-o|fileno|my|sleep|-p|flock|next|socket|-r|fork|not|socketpair|-R|format|oct|sort|-S|formline|open|splice|-s|getc|opendir|split|-T|getgrent|ord|sprintf|-t|getgrgid|our|sqrt|-u|getgrnam|pack|srand|-w|gethostbyaddr|pipe|stat|-W|gethostbyname|pop|state|-X|gethostent|pos|study|-x|getlogin|print|substr|-z|getnetbyaddr|printf|symlink|abs|getnetbyname|prototype|syscall|accept|getnetent|push|sysopen|alarm|getpeername|quotemeta|sysread|atan2|getpgrp|rand|sysseek|AUTOLOAD|getppid|read|system|BEGIN|getpriority|readdir|syswrite|bind|getprotobyname|readline|tell|binmode|getprotobynumber|readlink|telldir|bless|getprotoent|readpipe|tie|break|getpwent|recv|tied|caller|getpwnam|redo|time|chdir|getpwuid|ref|times|CHECK|getservbyname|rename|truncate|chmod|getservbyport|require|uc|chomp|getservent|reset|ucfirst|chop|getsockname|return|umask|chown|getsockopt|reverse|undef|chr|glob|rewinddir|UNITCHECK|chroot|gmtime|rindex|unlink|close|goto|rmdir|unpack|closedir|grep|say|unshift|connect|hex|scalar|untie|cos|index|seek|use|crypt|INIT|seekdir|utime|dbmclose|int|select|values|dbmopen|ioctl|semctl|vec|defined|join|semget|wait|delete|keys|semop|waitpid|DESTROY|kill|send|wantarray|die|last|setgrent|warn|dump|lc|sethostent|write|each|lcfirst|setnetent|__DATA__|else|lock|qw|__END__|elsif|lt|qx|__FILE__|eq|m|s|__LINE__|exp|ne|sub|__PACKAGE__|for|no|tr|and|foreach|or|unless|cmp|ge|package|until|continue|gt|q|while|CORE|if|qq|xor|do|le|qr|y|ARGV|STDERR|STDOUT|ARGVOUT|STDIN)/g
```

Comment: Wow, really good idea thank you. I am going to try this out it should work!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat single and double quotes in a special way, the answer is to TRY to match them just like you're matching the keywords.  Then you just do an additional step to filter all of your matches based off what you captured.

Two additional tips

- Don't include capture groups `(...)` inside a cached regular expression `qr{}` that is going to be interpolated in a greater regex.  Instead using a non-capturing group `(?:...)`.  This is because you want to be able to see exactly what is being captured when you do your test without having to scroll up to determine the exact coding of the included regexes.
- Don't forget your word boundary `\b` when trying to match a specific word.

The following is how I'd recode your attempt:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $singlequote_re = qr{'(?:(?>[^']+)|\\.)*'};
my $doublequote_re = qr{"(?:(?>[^"]+)|\\.)*"};
my $keywords_re = qr/(?:-A|END|length|setpgrp|-B|endgrent|link|setpriority|-b|endhostent|listen|setprotoent|-C|endnetent|local|setpwent|-c|endprotoent|localtime|setservent|-d|endpwent|log|setsockopt|-e|endservent|lstat|shift|-f|eof|map|shmctl|-g|eval|mkdir|shmget|-k|exec|msgctl|shmread|-l|exists|msgget|shmwrite|-M|exit|msgrcv|shutdown|-O|fcntl|msgsnd|sin|-o|fileno|my|sleep|-p|flock|next|socket|-r|fork|not|socketpair|-R|format|oct|sort|-S|formline|open|splice|-s|getc|opendir|split|-T|getgrent|ord|sprintf|-t|getgrgid|our|sqrt|-u|getgrnam|pack|srand|-w|gethostbyaddr|pipe|stat|-W|gethostbyname|pop|state|-X|gethostent|pos|study|-x|getlogin|print|substr|-z|getnetbyaddr|printf|symlink|abs|getnetbyname|prototype|syscall|accept|getnetent|push|sysopen|alarm|getpeername|quotemeta|sysread|atan2|getpgrp|rand|sysseek|AUTOLOAD|getppid|read|system|BEGIN|getpriority|readdir|syswrite|bind|getprotobyname|readline|tell|binmode|getprotobynumber|readlink|telldir|bless|getprotoent|readpipe|tie|break|getpwent|recv|tied|caller|getpwnam|redo|time|chdir|getpwuid|ref|times|CHECK|getservbyname|rename|truncate|chmod|getservbyport|require|uc|chomp|getservent|reset|ucfirst|chop|getsockname|return|umask|chown|getsockopt|reverse|undef|chr|glob|rewinddir|UNITCHECK|chroot|gmtime|rindex|unlink|close|goto|rmdir|unpack|closedir|grep|say|unshift|connect|hex|scalar|untie|cos|index|seek|use|crypt|INIT|seekdir|utime|dbmclose|int|select|values|dbmopen|ioctl|semctl|vec|defined|join|semget|wait|delete|keys|semop|waitpid|DESTROY|kill|send|wantarray|die|last|setgrent|warn|dump|lc|sethostent|write|each|lcfirst|setnetent|__DATA__|else|lock|qw|__END__|elsif|lt|qx|__FILE__|eq|m|s|__LINE__|exp|ne|sub|__PACKAGE__|for|no|tr|and|foreach|or|unless|cmp|ge|package|until|continue|gt|q|while|CORE|if|qq|xor|do|le|qr|y|ARGV|STDERR|STDOUT|ARGVOUT|STDIN)/;

while (<DATA>) {
    print "Line = $_";
    while (m{($singlequote_re)|($doublequote_re)|(\b$keywords_re\b)}g) {
        my $singlequote = $1;
        my $doublequote = $2;
        my $keyword = $3;

        if (defined $singlequote) {
            print "  Single quote = <$singlequote>\n";

        } elsif (defined $doublequote) {
            print "  Double quote = <$doublequote>\n";

        } elsif (defined $keyword) {
            print "  Keyword = <$keyword>\n";
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
return 3 + 4 if $string eq "time is eq";
```

Outputs:

```
Line = return 3 + 4 if $string eq "time is eq";
  Keyword = <return>
  Keyword = <if>
  Keyword = <eq>
  Double quote = <"time is eq">
```

Note, if this was anything but an exercise, the proper advice is for you to use [`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI) as trying to parse perl with regex's is kind of a fools errand.  There will always be edge cases, so using an actual lexer is only way to truly solve this.